# Wordpress ajax: submit form then go to homepage instead of replacing html tag

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I tried many times but it does not work as I expect to. I have a form submit a company name back to wordpress ajax to query AD in order to get a list of users. However, everytime I hit submit button, it just loads the homepage of the website. Please look at and show me the incorrect point in my code

Here is the code in function.php

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('directory_script',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/directory.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('directory_script');

    wp_register_script('directory1_script',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/directory1.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('directory1_script');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_scripts');

// buildDirectory function
function buildDirectory () {

$Company = $_GET["companyname"];

$ad = "ad1.p.local";
$result1;
   exec("ping -n 3 " . $ad, $output, $result1);
   if ($result1 != 0) { 
      $ad = "ad2.p.local"; 
      exec("ping -n 3 " . $ad, $output, $result1); }
   elseif ($result1 != 0) { 
      $ad = "ad3.p.local"; 
      exec("ping -n 3 " . $ad, $output, $result1); }
   //else { echo "Unable to get contact"; }

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($ad);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die("Unable to set LDAP protocol version");
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); 
$result;
$ldap_password = "abc";
$ldap_username = "cde";
$bind = ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password);
//$Company = "Patrick Industries";
   //if (TRUE === $bind) 
   //     {echo "Binding is successful<br />";}
   //else {echo "Binding is unsuccessful<br />";}
if (TRUE === $bind) {
    $ldap_base_dn = "DC=p,DC=local";
    $search_filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(company=$Company))";
        $attributes = array();
        $attributes[] = 'givenname';
        $attributes[] = 'mail';
        $attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
        $attributes[] = 'sn';
        $attributes[] = 'telephonenumber';
        $attributes[] = 'company';
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);        
    if (FALSE !== $result) {
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
//        echo "<br />Found " . $entries["count"] . " entries <br />";
        echo "<h4>List of contacts:</h4><br />";
        echo "<table><tr>
                         <th style='font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;width:150px'>Name</th>
                         <th style='font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;width:120px'>Phone</th>
                         <th style='font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;width:220px'>Email</th>
                         <th style='font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;width:160px'>Company</th>
                     </tr><tr>";
           $count1 = 0;
           for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
            if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['telephonenumber'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0]))
               { echo "<td>". $entries[$x]['givenname'][0] . " " . $entries[$x]['sn'][0] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>". $entries[$x]['telephonenumber'][0] . "</td>"; 
                 echo "<td><a href=mailto:" . $entries[$x]['mail'][0] . ">" . $entries[$x]['mail'][0] . "</a></td>"; 
                 echo "<td>". $entries[$x]['company'][0] . "</td></tr>"; 
                 $count1++; } 
//                 { $user = $entries[$x]['givenname'][0] . " " . $entries[$x]['sn'][0] . " , " . $entries[$x]['telephonenumber'][0] . " , " . "<a href=mailto:" . $entries[$x]['mail'][0] . ">" . $entries[$x]['mail'][0] . "</a>" . " , " . $entries[$x]['company'][0] . " .<br />";}
            }
//        echo "There are " . $count1 . " contacts";
        echo "</table>";
           }
      }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_bDirectory','buildDirectory');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bDirectory','buildDirectory');
```

Here is js file

```
// Have to include in .js file
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var ajaxurl = "http://<ip>/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";

// build directory through form submission
            $j("#company").submit(function(){
                //var cname = $j("#cname").val();
                var str = $(this).serialize();
                $j.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { action: "bDirectory", "cname": str },
                    success: function(html) {
                        $j("#company").replaceWith(html);
                        $j("#load").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here is HTML code

```
<form id="company" action="#">
<input id="cname" name="companyname" type="text"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the form from being submitted "the normal way":

```
$j("#company").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the form default action to be triggered
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $j.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "GET",
        data: { action: "bDirectory", "cname": str },
        success: function(html) {
            $j("#company").replaceWith(html);
            $j("#load").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
In functions.php you use `$_GET["companyname"];` but in your javascript you send `data: { action: "bDirectory", "cname": str },`, this should be corrected before anything.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work out, the problem is remaining. Should I have a return inside the function in function.php?

Comment: @new-learner any way we can check this on the actual website (or any development/staging server)?

Comment: Yes, I have an actual server which is running and am working on it. I modified the js file then replace the one in theme js folder. Then refresh the page and submit form again. It is still there. Is my send in js and receive in function cause the issue or the way that handle form submit?

Comment: @new-learner actually I was wondering if you had a URL to provide for testing purpose.
Have you tried to see if Chrome DevTools' Console displayed any error? (ensure the "Preserve Logs" checkbox is checked)

Comment: Maybe not, because it is internal server so I cannot publish that. Thanks for your response